# Delete rows from 2 tables using a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete

I have the following database-schema:

[image: Database-Schema]

I have the following example data:

```
CREATE TABLE computermapping (
  ComputerMappingID int NOT NULL,
  PrinterGUID char(36) NOT NULL,
  ComputerGUID char(36) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO computermapping (ComputerMappingID, PrinterGUID, ComputerGUID) VALUES
(1, 'PRT01', 'Computer1'),
(2, 'PRT02', 'Computer1'),
(3, 'PRT01', 'Computer2'),
(4, 'PRT02', 'Computer2'),
(5, 'PRT03', 'Computer2'),
(6, 'PRT01', 'Computer3');

CREATE TABLE computerdefaultprinter (
  ComputerGUID char(36) NOT NULL,
  PrinterGUID char(36) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO computerdefaultprinter (ComputerGUID, PrinterGUID) VALUES
('Computer2', 'PRT01'),
('Computer1', 'PRT02');
```

*Remark: Originally the tables are full of GUIDs, but I replaced them by names just for better readability.*

I have also created an **SQL-Fiddle** with some example-data: [Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/941700/2)

.

Taking the example data, I want to remove the printer "**PRT01**" from computer "**Computer2**".

I need to delete the appropriate row in the table `computermapping` and I need to delete the appropriate row in the table `computerdefaultprinter`. I want to delete the mentioned data in BOTH tables using ONE SINGLE statement.

According to my program-code I need to target the data by using `NOT IN()`.
Till now I successfully used 2 statements joined/glued together by ";":

```
DELETE FROM computermapping WHERE PrinterGUID = 'PRT01' AND ComputerGUID NOT IN ('Computer1','Computer3');
DELETE FROM computerdefaultprinter WHERE PrinterGUID = 'PRT01' AND ComputerGUID NOT IN ('Computer1','Computer3')
```

This was working fine using MySQL, but it is not working with Microsoft SQL-Server. Yes, it does using the SQL Server Management Studio, but not programmatically. (count field incorrect or syntax error)

I am looking for a different approach for this task.
I did a research and it was mentioned, that it should be possible to delete the rows in both tables using "INNER JOIN", but I wasn't able to get it working and I am looking for help.

Thank you

Comment: The bad news is that most databases don't allow you to delete rows from *different* tables in one `delete`.  The good news is that you can use cascading foreign key constraints or transactions to have effectively the same functionality.  In your case, though, just issue two `delete` commands.

Comment: Add the missing foreign key with `ON DELETE CASCADE` and off you go.

Comment: @TheImpaler I have not ever used something like this. Is it possible to give an example?

Comment: What do you mean by "but not programmatically"?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: I use PDO in PHP and running the mentioned query throws an error. I believe because of 2 results ...

Comment: So really.. there is no problem at all with any of the SQL here, the problem is really with PDO and PHP. You should provide that code and change the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a foreign key with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE computermapping (
  ComputerMappingID int NOT NULL,
  PrinterGUID char(36) NOT NULL,
  ComputerGUID char(36) NOT NULL,
  primary key (ComputerGUID, PrinterGUID)
);

INSERT INTO computermapping (ComputerMappingID, PrinterGUID, ComputerGUID) VALUES
(1, 'PRT01', 'Computer1'),
(2, 'PRT02', 'Computer1'),
(3, 'PRT01', 'Computer2'),
(4, 'PRT02', 'Computer2'),
(5, 'PRT03', 'Computer2'),
(6, 'PRT01', 'Computer3');

CREATE TABLE computerdefaultprinter (
  ComputerGUID char(36) NOT NULL,
  PrinterGUID char(36) NOT NULL,
  foreign key (ComputerGUID, PrinterGUID) 
    references computermapping (ComputerGUID, PrinterGUID)
    on delete cascade
);

INSERT INTO computerdefaultprinter (ComputerGUID, PrinterGUID) VALUES
('Computer2', 'PRT01'),
('Computer1', 'PRT02');

delete from computermapping 
where PrinterGUID = 'PRT01' and  ComputerGUID = 'Computer2';
```

The `DELETE` deletes a row in `computermapping` and all related rows from `computerdefaultprinter` as well.

See running example at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/77486/1).